# A set X is convex if $\forall x,y \in X$, $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\in X$

Tags: convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Prove or disprove the following statement: A set X is convex if $\forall x,y \in X$, $\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\in X$. 

A set X is convex is  $\forall x,y\in X, \lambda \in [0,1] \implies \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in X$.  
I think that the statement doesn't hold and I tried to disprove it formally, but I couldn't. Should I be looking for counterexamples? Any hints?

Comment: Let $X$ be a field of characteristic not equal to 2.

Comment: @Aritra That looks like a rhetorical statement.

Comment: It is true for *closed* sets: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371147/prove-if-c-is-midpoint-convex-and-closed-then-its-a-convex-set.

Comment: @Aritra What do you mean? Take $\mathbb Z_3$, what is $\lambda \cdot 2$ to you when $\lambda$ is a real number?

Comment: It is false in general as Saucy O'Path has pointed out below. However, if $X$ is a subset of a Hilbert space and $X$ is closed + your condition. Then $X$ is indeed convex. :)

Answer (score 4):

That looks very much like a condition that $\Bbb Q$ would satisfy.

Comment: +1... Even if we restrict $\lambda$ to members of $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1],$ if $X=\{a2^{-b}:a\in \Bbb Z\land b\in \Bbb N\} $ then $\forall x,y\in X\;((x+y)/2\in X)$  But  $0,1\in X$ while $(2/3)0+(1/3)1=1/3\not \in X.$