# In normed spaces set A is convex iff $\frac{x+y}{2} \in A$ proof

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let A be a closed set in a normed space. Prove that A is convex $\iff$ $\forall{x, y \in A} $ we have $\frac{x+y}{2}\in A  $

---

Well, my definition of a convex set A is that $\forall \lambda \in [0,1]; x,y \in A$ we have $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in A$. I literally couldn't write anything else than the thesis when trying to prove both sides of the $\iff$. Is there some trick to be used? Why is the space being normed important?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This is sometimes called *midpoint convex*. Knowing this keyword, you can find some other posts on this topic: [Prove if C is midpoint convex and closed then its a convex set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1371147)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, this is not true. Take for instance $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. It satisfies the property, but it is not convex.

However, if you assume the set to be closed, then it is true. Indeed, the $\Rightarrow$ way is easy (just take $\lambda=1/2$) in the definition of convexity. For the reverse way, prove inductively that for all $n \geq 1$, for all $k \in \lbrace 0, ..., 2^n \rbrace$, the definition of convexity is true for $\lambda=k/2^n$. And finally use a density argument to extand that to all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Whoops - my bad. The set is closed in the example. I have edited the question.

Comment: what is the density argument?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев You have to deduce the property for all $\lambda$ from the fact that it holds for all the $\lambda = k/2^n$... This can be done by taking a limit, since all the $\lambda \in [0,1]$ can be written as a limit of elements of the form $k/2^n$.