# Is it true that If $A + A = 2A$ in a TVS then $A$ is convex? what if we assume A is complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

We know that if $A$ is convex then it implies that $ A + A = 2A$ by simple arguments.

$2A \subset A + A $ this always holds.
Now
Let $ u+v \in A + A $ for some $u,v \in A$
Then $ (u+v)/2 \in A $ since A is convex.
Therefore $ 2×(u+v)/2 = u+v \in 2A$

Now Does converse hold?
If not then does converse hold if we assume tvs is complete?

My try:
Let $u,v \in A$
Then $u + v \in 2A \implies (u+v)/2 \in A$.

Now repeating this arguments for diff pairs of $u/2^n$ and $v/2^m$ .

We get all dyadic coefficients of $u$ and $v$.
So if we assume A to be complete we can get $u+v$ as well.
That is my idea but I don't know how to write it formally?

Can you provide counter eg or proof if we don't assume completeness?

Comment: Assume it as a vector space over $R $or $C$

Comment: But $Q$ is not complete. Assume $A$ to be complete

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: $A+A\subset 2A$ implies $A$ is midpoint convex $[\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}y\in A]$ $$\text{Closed+midpoint convex}\implies \text{convex}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $C$ is midpoint-convex and closed then it is a convex set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371147/if-c-is-midpoint-convex-and-closed-then-it-is-a-convex-set)